# Injecting javascript from ASP.NET webcontrol

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-controls

I'm making an ASP.NET webforms application and I have a problem with injecting a script into the page from a web control. The script is located in the same folder as control:

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4Geh.png)

So I'm trying like:

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:MyWebControl runat=server></{0}:MyWebControl>")]
[System.Drawing.ToolboxBitmap(typeof(MyWebControl))]
public class MyWebControl : Image
{

    //...

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);


        string scriptStr = "<script src=\"my_script.js\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
        ClientScriptManager csm = Page.ClientScript;
        csm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page.GetType(), "MyScriptTag", scriptStr);

        //...
    }

}
```

When I check if the script got injected successfully, Chrome gives me this:

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZEUJ.png)

I guess the problem is connected with `script src=\"my_script.js\"`, but I tried changing the path for long with no success.

Looking forward for some help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the path to the javascript file to be relative to the page that the user control is being rendered within. I'm assuming that the user control is being loaded by your index.aspx in your web project. Add a Scripts folder to the web project and move the javascript file there. Then, change the `src` to

`src=\"/Scripts/my_script.js\"`

Comment: Great, that worked! But it's not precisely what I meant. Is it possible to somehow encapsulate the script file in the location I originally placed it? I would like to have it in the first project

Comment: You would need to set the script as an embedded resource and follow additional steps to implement it properly. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398930.aspx - this is an older doc, but should be relevant to what you're trying to do.